# Laravel 7 saving / updating record with multiple associations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, relationship, laravel-7

```
**Opportunities Model**

public function client()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}

public function opportunityStage()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\OpportunityStage');
}

public function opportunityLossReason()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\OpportunityLossReason');
}

public function opportunityNotes()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\OpportunityNote');
}

**Client Model**

public function opportunities()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Opportunity');
}

**OpportunityStage Model**

public function opportunities()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Opportunity');
}

**OpportunityLossReason Model**

public function opportunities()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Opportunity');
}

**OpportunityNote Model**

public function opportunity()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Opportunity');
}

Request Data Coming From API

$data = [
   'client_id' => 1,
   'opportunity_stage_id' => 2,
   'opportunity_loss_reason_id' => 3,
   'opportunity_notes' => [
      0 => ['id' => 1,'text' => 'Test 1'] //Existing Note
      1 => ['text' => 'Test 2'] //New Note
   ]
]
```

If I wanted to add or update above opportunity what is the best method to achieve this. I am new to laravel and the orm. I read the documentation however not being able to figure out how to save / update a record with multiple associations. Do I need to save each association separately ?

Comment: have you gone through `attach` method and what u tried with that?

Comment: @phpdroid I have used it to for many to many relationship. However the record I am trying to save belong to 3 different model client, stage and loss reason